Next-Auth, does extending the session/jwt reflect changes on first session fetch or only on re-sign-in?
I want to extend the Session/Jwt object in Next-auth so that I have access to the user id aswell.
Now, I managed that, but I am unsure about one thing: say this change gets deployed to dev/production and users already logged in won't have to sign in again.
Does that mean the session won't have access to those user ids? I have read somewhere that useSession() would force a token refetch and it would therefore put the id in the session
This is from the documentation:

JWT Callback:

callbacks: {
  async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
    // Persist the OAuth access_token and or the user id to the token right after signin
    if (account) {
      token.accessToken = account.access_token
      token.id = profile.id
    }
    return token
  }
}


The arguments user, account, profile and isNewUser are only passed the
first time this callback is called on a new session, after the user
signs in. In subsequent calls, only token will be available."

So, what will happen to users already logged in, that have an active session (?), if I deploy the changes for session extension? Will data.user.id from useSession() just be undefined until they sign in again?
